# QSerialPort and Virtual Port Emulator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, virtual-serial-port, qtserial

I've got problem with my program based on QSerialPort class. I've created reciever application for my bluetooth module HC-06 (which connects to pc as serial port) and my app has recieved data from this module without any troubles. Now I've just wrote another app which should simulate transmitter. Then I tried to use program Free Virtual Serial Port to create a bridge between two virtual serial ports. And after that some problems occure. The reciever app does not emit readyRead() signal even thought I write data to bridged serial port via tranmiter app. When I disconnet reciever and connect to the same port via Hercules terminal all buffered data are shown.

What am i doing wrong? Is there any option to make it work?
I am using qt creator 2.8.1 based on qt 5.1.1 on windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Could you please try the latest from git/stable? We have had some virtual port related fixes lately.

Comment: Do you mean - try lates 'qt'?

Comment: I meant the latest QtSerialPort code from git.

Answer (score 1):

@user3148625,

if you talk about this software: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-virtual-serial-ports

then I do not recommend to use it, because this software works with errors (IMHO, bad software).

For example, in attempt to create "bridge" and further to open port by any of terminal program, will be a fail.

E.g. I used Windows 8x32 and set of this terminal programs:

1. Termite: http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm

this program is crashed in attempt to open port

1. Tera Term Pro: http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/ttssh2/releases/

after attempt to open port, this program starts to receive an streaming of trash and also is crashed.

I am sure, that other programs will behave also. I.e. a problem not in QtSerialPort but in a bad drivers of "Free Virtual Serial Port" software. It is an old known problem.

Thus I advise to use com0com the emulator: http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/

Or any other software (e.g. trial version of Eltima Software virtual ports).